# Revtex multiple authors with no affiliations - how to put equal contribution as footnote?

Tags: footnotes, revtex

I have a document with multiple authors. I normally add `\affiliation{University Name}` and `\altaffiliation{These authors contributed equally to this work}`. However, I now want to not display any affiliation but still have the equal contributions in the footnote of the first page. If I only use `\altaffiliation` I get a blank space, a comma and then the altaffiliation marker.

My MWE is below

```
\documentclass[aps,preprintnumbers,nofootinbib,superscriptaddress,11pt]{revtex4}
\begin{document}
\title{Blah Blah}
\author{Author 1}
\altaffiliation{These authors contributed equally to this work}
\author{Author 2}
\altaffiliation{These authors contributed equally to this work}
\author{Author 3}
\maketitle
text text text
\end{document}
```

As you can see, it doesn't work properly. If I use `\affiliation` instead of `\altaffiliation` it displays it right under the author list whereas I want it as a footnote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put the symbol in the author names manually and use a footnote without corresponding symbol in the text using `\footnotetext`. To get the same symbol you can temporarily change the footnote symbol before the `\footnotetext` command and change it back afterwards.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[aps,preprintnumbers,nofootinbib,superscriptaddress,11pt]{revtex4}
% geometry just for the screenshot
\usepackage[paperheight=100mm,paperwidth=210mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\title{Blah Blah}
\author{Author 1$^*$}
\author{Author 2$^*$}
\author{Author 3}
\maketitle
\def\thefootnote{*}\footnotetext{These authors contributed equally to this work}\def\thefootnote{\arabic{footnote}}
text text text\footnote{normal footnote}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Note that the extra symbol might end up in the document metadata (i.e., PDF properties) or if you have a header with the author names in it for example - there are workarounds for that as well.

Comment: Thank you - this works. Could you break down the command \def\thefootnote{*}\footnotetext{These authors contributed equally to this work} to help me understand why this works?

Comment: The `\thefootnote` command controls the appearance of the footnote symbol (the superscript numbers ¹²³ etc). Normally this is defined as the value of the footnote counter displayed in arabic (=normal) numbers, which is implemented as `\def\thefootnote{\arabic{footnote}}` (read: define the `\footnote` command as `\arabic{footnote}`). For your contribution footnote you want the symbol to be *. So you first define the footnote symbol to be * (`\def\thefootnote{*}`), then you print the footnote with `\footnotetext`, then you redefine the symbol according to the original definition.